# Android: package com.google.api.services.gmail does not exist

Tags: android, gmail-api

As by documentation: https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client

```
To use Gradle, add the following lines to your build.gradle file:

repositories {
    mavenCentral() } 

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.18.0-rc' }
```

Done, but I get:

```
Error: package com.google.api.services.gmail does not exist
```

What could be the reason ?

Comment: Did you sync project with gradle?

Comment: @wisemann: yes, of course

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding Google API and trying to use Gmail API. That is why getting `Error: package com.google.api.services.gmail does not exist`.If you want to use Gmail API add Gmail API Client Library by adding `compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev29-1.20.0'`

Ref: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/gmail/v1

Comment: Yes, I just found it out by myself looking at the file google-api-services-gmail-v1-rev29-1.20.0.jar in the directory. Thanks. It should be documented anyway!

Answer (score 1):

```
com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.20.0
```

on Android Studio->Project Structure->Dependencies-> "+"
you can navigate on repository declared in the gradle and choose the current version available
[image]